# The dash_html_components package is deprecated. Please replace `import dash_html_components as html

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to use dash 2.0, I also replaced import style in my all files but the problem is occurring in-dash bootstrap, Is there any method by which I can upgrade dash bootstrap for smoother use in dash 2.0 rather than manually changing.

> /home/sarim/Desktop/biz-pulse-vm-20210727T040204Z-001/biz-pulse-vm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_bootstrap_components/_table.py:5:

UserWarning:
The dash_html_components package is deprecated. Please replace
`import dash_html_components as html` with `from dash import html`
import dash_html_components as html

> /home/sarim/Desktop/biz-pulse-vm-20210727T040204Z-001/biz-pulse-vm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash_extensions/enrich.py:7:

UserWarning:
The dash_core_components package is deprecated. Please replace
`import dash_core_components as dcc` with `from dash import dcc`
import dash_core_components as dcc

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wait for dash bootstrap to release an update that brings it up to using Dash v2.0. In the meantime, these are only warnings, not errors, and you don't need to worry about them. Dash v2.0 is backwards compatible, so your code should still run fine.

Comment: Yeah, but it is having some issues

Comment: Can you provide details? Your question only mentioned the warning messages.

Comment: thank you @coralvanda I had the same question

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated means this code is now not in use in dash framework new version. Instead of writing

`import dash_html_components as html` and `import dash_core_components as dcc`

write just

`from dash import Dash, html, dcc`

and to create Instances of dash write

`app = Dash(__name__)` instead of `app = dash.Dash(__name__)`

Remaining code will be same.