# cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have upgraded dash to 2.x, Now in production I am using dash 2.x and also I am using same import statement for dash 2.x but It is not working.

```
from dash import dcc, html
ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dash/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does uninstalling and reinstalling dash help? `pip3 uninstall dash` and `pip3 install dash`

Comment: Yep, It is not working

Comment: but when I try to run in REPL, it is working over there

Comment: How are your running your script when not using REPL? Does printing our the python path for both equal the same path, e.g. `which python`, `which python3`, `which python38` depending on what you are using to run your script vs. start a REPL session

Comment: similar debugging can be done in the script with : 
```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Additionally check if your script has a shebang line and remove it if it is there

Comment: also make sure you aren't naming your file dash.py or dcc.py as that would cause import errors as well

Comment: Take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314018/the-dash-html-components-package-is-deprecated-please-replace-import-dash-html

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work,